# Surjection of norms

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$) vector space. Suppose there exists two norms on $V$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\| \cdot\|_1 \leq \| \cdot \|_2.
\end{equation*}

Is it true that there always exists a surjection between the two different completions of $V$? That is, does there always exist a continuous $\mathbb{C}$-linear surjection ($\mathbb{R}$-linear surjection)
\begin{equation*}
\overline{V}^{\|\cdot \|_2} \twoheadrightarrow \overline{V}^{\|\cdot \|_1} \, ?
\end{equation*}

The particular example I have in mind is when $G$ is an infinite discrete countable group and $V = \mathbb{C}[G]$, the complex valued functions on $G$ with finite support. Then there is a surjection from the maxmial group $C^*$-algebra and the reduced $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: Do you really just mean "surjection", e.g. you are only asking about cardinalities, or do you mean "continuous linear surjection"?

Comment: That is what I mean, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Because you consider the identity map $(V,\|\cdot\|_2)\longmapsto(V,\|\cdot\|_1)$. The inequality between the norms shows that it is bounded.

It is not immediately obvious to me that it is a surjection in the generality of your question. But it is in the concrete case you mention, because a C$^*$-homomorphism has closed image (when the domain is a C$^*$-algebra).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why does this not imply that there is a surjection from $C^*_r(G) \to C^*(G)$? We can define the inclusion $\mathbb{C}[G] \hookrightarrow C^*(G)$ hence we can extend this to $C^*_r(G) \to C^*(G)$ because $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is dense inside $C^*_r(G)$. Therefore we have a homomorphism with dense image. Since it is a $C^*$-homomorphism, the image is closed hence all of $C^*(G)$.

Comment: No, you cannot extend the inclusion because it is not bounded in general.

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no such surjection (the C*-case is quite special in that respect).

Indeed, let $V=c_{00}$ be the vector space of finitely supported vectors. For $(\xi_n)$ in $V$ define $\|(\xi_n)\|_1 = \sup_n |\xi_n|$ and $\|(\xi_n)\|_2^p = \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\xi_k|^p$ for some fixed $p\in (1,\infty)$. Conspicuously, the respective completions are $c_0$ and $\ell_p$. Of course, $c_0$ is not a quotient of $\ell_p$ as the latter space is reflexive.